# PUT DateTime field in .NET API

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to update a DateTime field in my .NET API but it doesn't seem to be updating and it also doesn't seem to be complaining about anything.

Has anyone had an issue with DateTime in entities before?

I am using EF Core with a PostGres database.

Example Entity:

```
public class Example {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Example Json Body:

```
{ "date" : "2022-08-28T09:28:18.024" }
```

Comment: The question is unclear. There's no problem with dates. PostgreSQL and EF Core have nothing to do with HTTP, JSON or PUT. You didn't post any ASP.NET Core code. Does your `Put` method receive any data in the first place? Do you have any code that actually writes to the database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I personally would prevent using names for fields that are also objects, like Date, or for example public int String {get; set;}

I think the solution is to use the same casing as the field names, your field in object Example is named "Date", while in the json object you are naming it "date"

Have you tried debugging, and checking if the value is in the object before saving to the database? Then you know if the value is correctly translated from JSON to your object Example

Comment: That was just for example purposes. 

I am using swagger to post the date in the format that the swagger docs are suggesting to do, and I am getting a 200 but nothing is updating in the database. I will add a breakpoint into the method and see how it is being received in the code and will report back